# How to use Pundit to authorize admin users to see delayed job web?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, delayed-job, pundit

I am very new to *Rails* and *Ruby* but I am involved on a project as a trainee, which uses *Pundit* for authorization of users.

Our project uses `delayed_job_active_record` gem and I wanted to add `delayed_job_web` for a quick and easy view of jobs.

I can see that documentation for the latter gem uses basic rack authorisation or devise gem when matching or mounting the route to DelayedJobWeb.

I looked and googled but I couldn't find any suggestions on how to use *Pundit* instead (so that when you type the link yourself it doesn't allow you to see it unless you are an admin).

Any ideas of how this can be done please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your routes you could do something like this:

```
authenticate :user, lambda { |u| u.admin? } do          
  mount DelayedJobWeb => '/delayedjobweb'
end
```

Comment: Hi NEL, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this does not work for me as I am working with Pundit not Devise or Warden.